# How do you run a readable video file that closes when the video ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, path

Although I have no code to show or examples to present to you, I am in desperate need to learn how to play a video file on python and for it to quit once it ends to carry on any the program that is written afterwards.

Sorry in advance if this question doesn't follow stack overflows policies on a "good" question but it sparked my interest to query it.

Please reply to this with your ideas and topics I can research to gain a further understanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV Should allow you what you want to do using the `cv2.VideoCapture('file')` function.

Here is a code example:

```
# import required libraries 
import cv2 

# Create a VideoCapture object 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4') 

# Check if video file opened successfully 
if (cap.isOpened()== False):  
  print("Error opening video  file") 

# Read until video is completed 
while(cap.isOpened()): 

  # Capture frame-by-frame 
  ret, frame = cap.read() 
  if ret == True: 

    # Display the captured frame 
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame) 

  # Break the loop to close the video
  else:  
    break

# When everything done, release the video capture object 
cap.release() 

# Closes all the frames 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To install opencv on Windows 10:

- Open an Elevated Command Line - Right click the start button and press

  > Command Line (Admin)
- Run the command: `pip install opencv-python`

On Linux/Mac:

- Open the Terminal/Command Line
- Run: `sudo pip install opencv-python`
- Type in your password when prompted

Comment: I'm getting an error where the module cv2 isn't installed or something like that, how do I fix that?